# Laravel explode and join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem, I am requesting some data in the db and one of them are concatenated the field has form like this:

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | n-1 | n,
```

The problem is that every numerical value I have to join with another table.

```
$Metro  = DB::table('fijacion')->where('tipo','Metro')->join('adp', 'fijacion.id', '=', "adp.id_fijacion")->get();
```

The solution that occurred to me was that chain divide it so

```
foreach($Metro as $Metro){ 
    $array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);
    $MetroXI = DB::table('users')
              ->select('numero','nombre','apellido')
              ->whereIn('numero',$array)
              ->where('categoria', 1)
              ->join('puntos', 'users.numero', '=', "puntos.nr")
              ->orderBy('puntos.Total', 'asc')
              ->get();
 }
```

This breaks the chain, but it only shows me a result

I know it's confusing to understand but if someone could guide me how to make the forech correctly or some idea would be grateful

$Metro:

```
[{"id":1,"semana":32,"fecha":"2017-08-11","dia":"Viernes","tipo":"Metro","categoria":null,"hora":"20:30 ","cancha":"CAPITOL ","partido":"CAPITOL \u2013 TABAR\u00c9 ","nr_1":null,"arbitro_1":null,"nr_2":null,"arbitro_2":null,"nr_3":null,"arbitro_3":null,"aux":1,"updated_at":"2017-08-07 12:04:04","created_at":"2017-08-07 12:03:57","id_fijacion":1,"nr":"7|22|29|31|32|40|53|59|66|67|68|77|5|12|13|17|18|20|24|27|28|33|35|37|44|46|50|52|61|64|65|75|23|25|26|39|47|48|51|58|69|74|80|82|83|86|93|96|104|109|117|120","designado":0},{"id":2,"semana":32,"fecha":"2017-08-11","dia":"Viernes","tipo":"Metro","categoria":null,"hora":"20:30 ","cancha":"MIRAMAR ","partido":"MIRAMAR \u2013 COL\u00d3N ","nr_1":null,"arbitro_1":null,"nr_2":null,"arbitro_2":null,"nr_3":null,"arbitro_3":null,"aux":1,"updated_at":"2017-08-07 12:04:04","created_at":"2017-08-07 12:03:57","id_fijacion":2,"nr":"7|22|29|31|32|40|53|59|66|67|68|77|5|12|13|17|18|20|24|27|28|33|35|37|44|46|50|52|61|64|65|75|23|25|26|39|47|48|51|58|69|74","designado":0},{"id":3,"semana":32,"fecha":"2017-08-11","dia":"Viernes","tipo":"Metro","categoria":null,"hora":"20:30 ","cancha":"SAYAGO ","partido":"ATENAS \u2013 AURIBLANCO ","nr_1":null,"arbitro_1":null,"nr_2":null,"arbitro_2":null,"nr_3":null,"arbitro_3":null,"aux":1,"updated_at":"2017-08-07 12:04:04","created_at":"2017-08-07 12:03:57","id_fijacion":3,"nr":"28|33|35|37|44|46|50|52|61|64|65|75|23|25|26|39|47|48|51|58|69|74|80|82|83|86|93|96|104|109|117|120","designado":0},{"id":4,"semana":32,"fecha":"2017-08-11","dia":"Viernes","tipo":"Metro","categoria":null,"hora":"20:30 ","cancha":"CORD\u00d3N \u2013 SIN P\u00daBLICO VISITANTE ","partido":"CORD\u00d3N \u2013 25 DE AGOSTO ","nr_1":null,"arbitro_1":null,"nr_2":null,"arbitro_2":null,"nr_3":null,"arbitro_3":null,"aux":1,"updated_at":"2017-08-07 12:04:05","created_at":"2017-08-07 12:03:57","id_fijacion":4,"nr":"7|22|29|31|32|40|53|59|66|67|68|77|5|12|13|17|18|20|35|37|44|46|50|52|61|64|65|75|23|25|26|39|47|48|51|58|69|74|80|82|83|86|93|96|104|109|117|120","designado":0},{"id":5,"semana":32,"fecha":"2017-08-11","dia":"Viernes","tipo":"Metro","categoria":null,"hora":"20:30 ","cancha":"STOCKOLMO ","partido":"STOCKOLMO \u2013 UNI\u00d3N ATL\u00c9TICA ","nr_1":null,"arbitro_1":null,"nr_2":null,"arbitro_2":null,"nr_3":null,"arbitro_3":null,"aux":1,"updated_at":"2017-08-07 12:04:05","created_at":"2017-08-07 12:03:57","id_fijacion":5,"nr":"7|22|29|31|32|40|53|59|66|67|68|77|5|12|13|17|18|20|24|27|28|33|35|37|44|46|50|52|61|64|65|75|23|25|26|39|47|83|86|93|96|104|109|117|120","designado":0}]
```

In the nr values is where I have to join it

Thanks to @yoeunes loger avanasa but now in my view I have error.

Which I realized I did not relate $ Metro with $ MetroXI [ ]

Here are the parameters for my .blade
This is my view:

```
                @foreach($Metro as $Metro)
                    <tr>
                    <th>{{$Metro->dia}}</th>
                    <th>{{$Metro->fecha}}</th>
                    <th>{{$Metro->categoria}}</th>
                    <th>{{$Metro->hora}}</th>
                    <th>{{$Metro->cancha}}</th>
                    <th>{{$Metro->partido}}</th>
                    <th>@php$array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);$pepe = count($array);@endphp{{ $pepe }}</th>


                    <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="arbitro_1">
                        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º Arbitro</option>
                        <option disabled="disabled">---Internacional---</option>
                        @foreach($MetroXI as $MetroXI)
                          <option value="{{$MetroXI->numero}}">{{$MetroXI->nombre}}. {{$MetroXI->apellido}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

        @endforeach
```

The error you give me is:

> Property [nr] does not exist on this collection instance.

And occurs with the 3 variables.

Comment: What do you expect to be the result? Give some example

Comment: you're looping the same variable `foreach($Metro as $Metro)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

```
$MetroXI = [];
foreach($Metro as $Metro){ 
    $array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);
    $MetroXI[] = DB::table('users')
              ->select('numero','nombre','apellido')
              ->whereIn('numero',$array)
              ->where('categoria', 1)
              ->join('puntos', 'users.numero', '=', "puntos.nr")
              ->orderBy('puntos.Total', 'asc')
              ->get();
 }
```

and then check the `$MetroXI` array it will contain all the results;

Comment: Only returns me 1 result when they are more

Comment: @AlejandroMuñozSchumacher can you re-check my answer please

Comment: Hello again I am trying to relate $ Metro with $ MetroXI [] and I do not achieve it

Comment: inside the foreach you can do something like `$MetroXI[$Metro->id] = ...` to keep track of the Metro inside MetroX